# Which datastructure is better for huge Data - HashTable/HashMap or Array?

Tags: arrays, hashmap, comparison, hashtable

In terms of both performance and memory, what is better for huge volumes of data.

Data can be simply a key value pair. For example - Id and Count indicating # of times that Id has viewed a page.

It seems array is better memory-wise since it is contiguous memory. Is this right? Does it even impact performance?

Thank you!

Comment: All depends on how you want to access your data. Do you need keyed access by id?

Comment: yes. so I would be putting values into the datastructure one by one and say traverse through the entire set to find which ones have count (value) greater than say 5

Comment: Which one is it? yes, you need keyed access by id? or: no, you want to traverse the entire set to find counts greater than 5? Where is the data from? Do you need to update it (or just make reports from it)?

Comment: traverse it. dont need to update it.

Comment: Maybe no need to put it into memory at all. Just read through a file (if that is where the data is coming from).

Comment: you are being too specific. I'm asking for large data sets what we should consider when choosing a data structure. trade-offs/advantages/disadvantages etc..

Comment: you cannot evaluate the options and trade-offs without looking at the specific case